# Padding is invalid and cannot be removed in C#

Tags: c#, cryptography

I'm making a program with encryting and decrypting feature, but I have encountered **Padding is invalid and cannot be removed** problem.

Here are my codes:

*Encrypt*

```
public static string EncryptString(string plainText, string passPhrase)
        {
            byte[] initVectorBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("pemgail9uzpgzl88");
            byte[] plainTextBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plainText);
            PasswordDeriveBytes password = new PasswordDeriveBytes(passPhrase, null);
            byte[] keyBytes = password.GetBytes(256 / 8);
            RijndaelManaged symmetricKey = new RijndaelManaged();
            symmetricKey.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
            ICryptoTransform encryptor = symmetricKey.CreateEncryptor(keyBytes, initVectorBytes);
            MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
            CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write);
            cryptoStream.Write(plainTextBytes, 0, plainTextBytes.Length);
            cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();
            byte[] cipherTextBytes = memoryStream.ToArray();
            memoryStream.Close();
            cryptoStream.Close();
            return Convert.ToBase64String(cipherTextBytes);
        }
```

*Decrypt*

```
public static string DecryptString(string cipherText, string passPhrase)
    {
        byte[] initVectorBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("pemgail9uzpgzl88");
        byte[] cipherTextBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(cipherText);
        PasswordDeriveBytes password = new PasswordDeriveBytes(passPhrase, null);
        byte[] keyBytes = password.GetBytes(256 / 8);
        RijndaelManaged symmetricKey = new RijndaelManaged();
        symmetricKey.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
        ICryptoTransform decryptor = symmetricKey.CreateDecryptor(keyBytes, initVectorBytes);
        MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(cipherTextBytes);
        CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read);
        byte[] plainTextBytes = new byte[cipherTextBytes.Length];
        int decryptedByteCount = cryptoStream.Read(plainTextBytes, 0, plainTextBytes.Length);
        memoryStream.Close();
        cryptoStream.Close();
        return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(plainTextBytes, 0, decryptedByteCount);
    }
```

The process that is wrong is decrytping, at the line **cryptoStream.Close**.

Comment: There are some problems here, for instance you're closing the streams in the wrong order. Use `using(){}` blocks to fix that. Get the buffer from the MemoryStream after you have closed it.

Comment: But it looks like it still should work. Add a small sample for how you call it, I suspect the length of plainText could be a factor. Also specify the .NET version.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Can you explain more? I don't understand it

Comment: I use .NET Framework 4.0

Comment: First close the CryptoStream, then the MemStream, then get the bytes with  ToArray()

Comment: It still doesn't work

Comment: I just tested your code (w/o improvements) and it works fine. So post a [mcve] or delete this question.

Comment: You could be running into something that was changed/fixed in Fx4. I ran this on a PC that does have 4.5x and 4.6x installed.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the padding for both encryption and decryption.

```
symmetricKey.Padding=PaddingMode.PKCS7;
```

Also flush the final block when encrypting the data.

I tested the following code and it worked fine:

```
public static string Encrypt(string plainText, string passPhrase)
    {
        byte[] initVectorBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("pemgail9uzpgzl88");
        byte[] plainTextBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plainText);
        PasswordDeriveBytes password = new PasswordDeriveBytes(passPhrase, null);
        byte[] keyBytes = password.GetBytes(256 / 8);
        RijndaelManaged symmetricKey = new RijndaelManaged();
        symmetricKey.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
        symmetricKey.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
        ICryptoTransform encryptor = symmetricKey.CreateEncryptor(keyBytes, initVectorBytes);
        MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write);
        cryptoStream.Write(plainTextBytes, 0, plainTextBytes.Length);
        cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();
        byte[] cipherTextBytes = memoryStream.ToArray();
        memoryStream.Close();
        cryptoStream.Close();
        string cipherText = Convert.ToBase64String(cipherTextBytes);
        return cipherText;
    }

    public static string Decrypt(string cipherText, string passPhrase)
    {
        byte[] initVectorBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("pemgail9uzpgzl88");
        byte[] cipherTextBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(cipherText);
        PasswordDeriveBytes password = new PasswordDeriveBytes(passPhrase, null);
        byte[] keyBytes = password.GetBytes(256 / 8);
        RijndaelManaged symmetricKey = new RijndaelManaged();
        symmetricKey.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
        symmetricKey.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
        ICryptoTransform decryptor = symmetricKey.CreateDecryptor(keyBytes, initVectorBytes);
        MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(cipherTextBytes);
        CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read);
        byte[] plainTextBytes = new byte[cipherTextBytes.Length];
        int decryptedByteCount = cryptoStream.Read(plainTextBytes, 0, plainTextBytes.Length);
        memoryStream.Close();
        cryptoStream.Close();
        string plainText = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(plainTextBytes, 0, decryptedByteCount);
        return plainText;
    }
```

I've set the padding for encryption and decryption, flushing the final block.
Try the code [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/fo3Bt2#).

Comment: I've encrypted the text from richTextBox so could this be the reason of the problem?

Comment: @WhourNary  When you get normal text it shouldn't matter. But we can't look on your pc so start writing that [mcve]. It only takes a Console app and at most 5 extra lines.